# solve IOS 14 issue in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, ios14

I'm set google analytics in tag manager to upload events from my website, but because the IOS 14 issue I can't upload events from IOS 14 devices, so how can I solve this problem, note: I have the events in my database?

Answer (score 0):

To bypass iOS 14+ blocking, you need to use a GTM server container along with your web container.
Currently, all data that is sent from your site to third parties is blocked through iOS or Adblocks.

The solution is to download GTM scripts from your subdomain (not from googletagmanager.com) and send data not directly to google analytics, but to the GTM container server, from where it is already sent to analytics. That way the data will not be blocked.

Here is a more detailed description and links to step-by-step instructions on how to make the GTM container server setup: https://stape.io/how-to-prevent-your-google-analytics-data-from-being-blocked-by-adblockers/

Comment: but what about Measurement Protocol, is it another solution or what ?