# Can I use Google analytics measurement protocol to solve IOS 14 issue?

Tags: google-analytics, ios14, measurement-protocol

I'm set google analytics in tag manager to upload events from my website, but because the IOS 14 issue I can't upload events from IOS 14 devices in some browsers, so can I use measurement protocol to upload the events ? If yes, does Google Analytics remove duplication between the browser and offline conversions ?
Note: I have the events in my database with only gclid parameter and Conversion time, so if there is a duplication in events(I upload the same event from both Google Analytics and measurement protocol) is it will take one event and removed other depend on gclid or both gclid and time ?

Comment: The ios14 changes shouldn't affect Google Analytics because GA uses first party cookies: https://www.morevisibility.com/blogs/analytics/apples-ios14-update-and-its-effects-on-google-analytics.html

Comment: But what about this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69928864/solve-ios-14-issue-in-google-analytics he says you must use GTM server container to solve IOS issue, Is it correct ?